# Black screen after installation Latest Nvidia Driver 340.46 via PPA in Ubuntu 14

Tags: nvidia, updates, gpu-driver, 14.10

Just couple minutes ago I tried to install Latest Nvidia Driver 340.46 via PPA in Ubuntu.
For this reason I used this
[instruction](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/10/install-latest-nvidia-340-46-via-ppa/)

The following commands weere executed:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mamarley/nvidia
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install nvidia-340

After reboot I see only black screen and that all.

How can I fix it?

Comment: can you switch to tty by pressing ctrl + alt + F1 ? or this is only black screen with blinking cursor ?

Comment: @EdiD, yes,this is only black screen with blinking cursor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't switch to tty by *ctrl + alt + F1* combination you have to launch rescue mode. You can do it by holding shift after post test (before ubuntu start launching). Now select you want to have network connection and go to root command. You have to remount your drive from read only to full access:

> mount -o remount,rw /

Now purge your current nvidia drivers installation by:

> apt-get purge nvidia*

and restore older driver:

> apt-get install nvidia-current

Now you can try to reboot.
(and in farther way install e.g nvidia 331 drivers)

Answer (score 3):

It could be a package problem or driver problem.

Change to tty: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

Try to remove the `xorg.conf` file by doing in the terminal the following command: `sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`. Then try to create a new on by doing in the terminal the following command: `sudo nvidia-xconfig`

If it still doesn't work, remove the driver and install the normal:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove --purge nvidia-*  #note this command will also remove the ubuntu-desktop package!!!
```

After: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Final: `apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-331-dev nvidia-331-uvm nvidia-settings`

Comment: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx recommends to install Linux display driver: Version:  340.46.

Comment: Deleting xorg.conf worked for me.